# Check multiple conditions in lists (loop for)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem checking multiple conditions at once.

```
import itertools

def repeats(input1, input2):
    return [int(dz) for dz in input1 if int(dz) in input2]

n_combs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

filters = [[[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22], [5]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7]], [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [2]]]

combinacoes = itertools.combinations(n_combs, 15)

for comb in combinacoes:
    for filtro, maxx in filters:

        if len(repeats(filtro, comb)) in maxx:
            print(comb)
```

Basically, I need a combination to only print if:

- contain `5` items from this list: `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22]`
- contain `7` items from this list: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`
- contain `2` items from this list: `[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]`

The above code does not do the 3 validations at the same time and that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to apply an arbitrary number of tests to some value.

Since in Python functions are first class citizens, you can have a list of validator functions:

```
def iterable_contains_1(value):
    return 1 in value

def iterable_contains_2(value):
    return 2 in value

validators = [iterable_contains_1, iterable_contains_2]
```

Then you can call all your validations:

```
for item in ([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]):
    if all(validator(item) for validator in validators):
        print('do something with', item)
```

This will print only `do something with [1, 2, 3]` as it is the only list passing both tests.

[edit]

I think you are looking for `set`.

```
def validator1(iterable):
    return len(
        set(iterable).intersection(
            [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22]
        )) >= 5

def validator2(iterable):
    return len(
        set(iterable).intersection(
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
        )) >= 7

def validator3(iterable):
    return len(
        set(iterable).intersection(
            [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
        )) >= 2
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how your code could solve my problem. Could you use my problem data as an example?

Remembering that I used only 2 filters / list only to facilitate the commissioning. Consider that there are hundreds

Comment: This code is not good, because I have thousands of lists to be tested, and creating a function for each one is not correct.

Comment: How rude! Clearly you can abstract the logic (hint, the only difference between the functions is the list and the number of coincidences). Bear in mind that  stackoverflow is not a coding-for-free service. Volunteers here are trying to help you and you pay them with harsh criticism?

Comment: Sorry if I was offended you, that was not my intention. I just wanted to say that your code did not fit the one I needed. Thank you very much for your willingness to help, really. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop is working properly only that the last element in `filters` does not meet the conditions you have specified. Edit it to include smaller numbers like I have done below. Also, I have reduced the number of elements in `n_combs` so that my answer becomes easy to understand. This is because looping through the more than 3 million entries in `25 combination 15` is not a very good idea for demonstration purposes. Try to run the edited version below and you will see what I am saying.

```
import itertools

def repeats(input1, input2):
    return [int(dz) for dz in input1 if int(dz) in input2]

n_combs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

filters = [[[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22], [5]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7]], [[2, 4, 7,9], [2]]]

combinacoes = itertools.combinations(n_combs, 15)

for comb in combinacoes:
    for filtro, maxx in filters:

        if len(repeats(filtro, comb)) in maxx:
            print(comb, maxx)
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I think you did not understand. The code is not doing the 3 validations at the same time. Consider using this instead of what I passed `filters = [[[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22], [1, 3, 4] 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution:

```
import itertools

def repeats(input1, input2):
    return [int(dz) for dz in input1 if int(dz) in input2]

n_combs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

filters = [[[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 22], [5]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7]], [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [2]]]

combinacoes = itertools.combinations(n_combs, 15)

for comb in combinacoes:
    if all([len(repeats(filtro, comb)) in qtd for filtro, qtd in filters]):
        print(comb)
```

Remembering that the values used in this post were just examples, to simplify and better understand logic.

Now the algorithm is able to validate a combination on all filters at the same time, and allow one condition to be satisfied for all.